# Correct desugaring of this Do block

Tags: haskell

Here is the original do block:

```
triples = do
   z <- [1..]
   x <- [1..z]
   y <- [x..z]
   guard (x^2 + y^2 == z^2)
   return (x, y, z)

guard :: Bool -> [()]
guard True = [()]
guard False = []
```

My interpretation of the desugared block using binds:

```
triples = do
   [1..] >>= \z ->
      [1..z] >>= \x ->
         [x..z] >>= \y ->
            guard(x^2 + y^2 == z^2) >>= \_ ->
               return(x,y,z)
```

So, my understanding is that this will generate something like:
`[[[[(x,y,z)], [(x2,y2,z2)],[(xn,yn,zn)]]]]` and then binds concat each layer of the brackets.

Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: Not exactly.  Each bind eliminates its own layer of the brackets as it goes, so there's never such a deep nesting.

Comment: Your desugaring is correct. Each bind is actually `concatMap` so it will flatten lists at each step. There's no deeply-nested list that gets flattened only at the very end.